# Lightbox 2 - how to apply options

Tags: jquery, lightbox2

I want to apply this code by using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function());

<script>
    lightbox.option({
      'resizeDuration': 200,
      'wrapAround': true
    })
</script>
```

How can I apply this ligthbox option by using "`jQuery(document).ready(function());`

Answer (score 0):

If you want use jQuery(document).ready(); you should wrap this like:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   lightbox.option({
      'resizeDuration': 200,
      'wrapAround': true
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to used "options" then you can add option(alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices) the place of option like this...

```
    <scrpit>
lightbox.alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices({
      'resizeDuration': 200,
      'wrapAround': true
    })</script>
```

or
if u used in jquery then ...

```
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   lightbox.option({
      'resizeDuration': 200,
      'wrapAround': true
    });
});
</script>
```